# Measure is countably additive

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space . Let ${E_n}$ be a sequence of measurable subsets of $X$ such that $\mu(E_i\cap E_j)=0$ if $i$ and $j$ are not same. Then measure of union of $E_n$ is same as sum of $E_n$.
I know if the sets are disjoint then by definition the result follows.
But how to show in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=\bigcup_{i\neq j} (E_i \setminus E_j)$ (union over all pairs $(i,j)$ with $i \neq j$) and let $F_i =E_i \setminus \bigcup_{\{j: j \neq i\}} E_j$. Show that $\mu (A)=0$. Show that $\mu (E_i)=\mu (F_i)$ by showing that $E_i \subset F_i \cup A$ and $F_i \subset E_i \cup A$. Similarly show that $\mu (\bigcup E_i)=\mu (\bigcup F_i)$. Finally note that $F_i$'s are disjoint and use countable additivity for these sets.